# Check if valueForKey exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, request

i'm making a request which sometimes can return a error message example error:"no live games".

How can i check if the valueforkey: error exists?

pseudo

```
if (error exists) {
 //nothing
} else {
 //return other value for keys
}
```

my request

```
NSDictionary* headers3 = @{@"X-Mashape-Authorization": @"key"};
NSDictionary* parameters3 = @{};

UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response3 = [[UNIRest get:^(UNISimpleRequest* request3) {
    [request3 setUrl:@"https://willjw-statsfc-competitions.p.mashape.com/live.json?key=uNzRmnUdCEYKdOoe1e1bBpwtmczNVLUZYbIlOX9O&competition=europa-league&timezone=Europe%2FLondon"];

    [request3 setHeaders:headers3];
    [request3 setParameters:parameters3];
}] asJson];


NSData* rawBody3 = [response3 rawBody];
results3 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rawBody3 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Comment: Show the sample JSON for success and error conditions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your API returns "message" instead of "error". Anyway, here's what you do:

```
if (result3[@"message"]) { // equavalent of [result3 objectForKey:@"message"], which will return nil if there's no "message" key in the dictionary
  // your error handler condition
}
else {
  // process retrieved data
}
```